# When searching for multiple words, does regex always match the largest word possible?

Tags: regex

If I have the following string:

```
banana
```

And I want to search for multiple strings by using the regular expression:

```
(a|ana|nana|banana)
```

Will the regular expression always match `banana` since this is the longest string?

Comment: What language? JavaScript? Python? Java?

Comment: perl and php. I didn't know the language mattered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a detail that may vary between regex implementations.  In general, I would expect `banana` to match, not because it is the longest, but because it has the leftmost starting position in the string - that match would be discovered before the starting position of any of the other alternatives had been reached.

If the regex was something like `(bana|ba|banana)`, the results are much less certain.  It could reasonably be any of `bana` (first alternative that matched), `ba` (first alternative for which the complete match was reached), or `banana` (longest match).  Hopefully the documentation of your regex implementation gives the exact rules it uses.

Comment: The key idea here is whether you are working with a **greedy** or **non-greedy** patterns and/or regex engines, and sometimes this behavior even varies between different metacharacters and constructs. Regex implementations usually support options and/or metacharacters which will alter this behavior (within a specific set of parenthesis, for example). Many common engines are by default greedy. That means at first match (i.e. the first character that matches) they will continue matching until the pattern is exhausted, _only backtracking if absolutely necessary_ to satisfy the pattern.

Comment: See (http://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html) for detailed explanation of the order in matching.  It also has links that better explain "greedy" and "lazy" matches.

Comment: This helped! Thank you so much for the response.